# Is there a class that holds both dateTime and Timespan together?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm looking for a class that represents an concurrent event,
for example: 
On every work day, meeting from 10:00 that takes 2 hours. etc..

I know how to implement it my self, i wondered if there is a predifined class.

tnx!

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Hi what do you need it for? Maybe if you describe your use case we can see what fits the best.

Comment: You can create your own.

Comment: I don't know of one, but writing it yourself shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make such a class immutable, and perhaps even a struct.

You can choose either a start/end or start/duration internal representation. Should be invisible to the public API.

If you're fancy you can overload a few operators and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to get full value semantics.

```
public class TimeInterval
{
    private readonly DateTime _start;
    private readonly DateTime _end;

    public DateTime Start { get { return _start; } }
    public DateTime End { get { return _end; } }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get { return _end - _start; } }

    public TimeInterval(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if(end.Kind != start.Kind)
          throw new ArgumentException("Incompatible DateTimes");

        _start = start;
        _end = end;
    }

    public TimeInterval(DateTime start, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        _start = start;
        _end = start.Add(duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mrnye No idea. But the `.Kind` change lost the intention of that check.

Answer (score 8):

No, but here's one to take home:

```
public class DateTimeAndTimeSpan
{
    public DateTime Time{get;set;}
    public TimeSpan Duration{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't like making such a class mutable.

Comment: It's funny how you can spend weeks lovingly crafting helpful answers to interesting questions, yet your highest scoring answer over that period is a blunt and somewhat silly answer to a very basic question. SO is a strange place! @CodeInChaos, I completely agree with you.